# py2exe generate custom Icon

Tags: python, icons, py2exe

So this is a question that has been asked many times. And I followed all the things found on the interwebs, however. My icon just isn't appearing, and I'm not getting any sort of error message. The rest of my program functions fine, it's just the darn ugly icon.

Here's my setup.py file, please let me know if/what I'm doing wrong? Sorry if there is a dumb error. :(

```
import os, os.path, sys
import subprocess
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import glob
import numpy

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

target = {
'script' : "MY_PROGRAM.py",
'version' : "1.0",
'company_name' : "MY_COMPANY",
'copyright' : "",
'name' : "PROGRAM_NAME", 
'dest_base' : "PROGRAM_NAME", 
'icon_resources': [(1, "MY_ICON.ico")]
}       

opts = {
        'py2exe': { 'includes': ['matplotlib.numerix.random_array', 'dbhash', 
        'anydbm', 'skimage', 'pymorph', 'register'],
        'excludes': ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg'],
        'dll_excludes': ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
        'libgobject-2.0-0.dll'],
        'bundle_files': 1
                   }
        }       


setup(
    data_files = [('Images', glob.glob('Images/*.*'))],
    windows = [target],
    zipfile = None
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

....

For some reason it works now. I used a different website to convert my png file to a .ico, and voila magic.

:( so much struggles